# Php or Jquery to overwrite css file to a path

Tags: php, jquery

I wish to overwrite (not override), a css file with the click of a button. Currently my button simply downloads the css file instead of writing it to a path on my server. I want to write my style.css file to /templates/mypath/style.css  and overwrite whenever the button is clicked. NOTE: I already have the button part working - Just need some ideas to overwrite the file to a path.

**Why am I doing this?**
I have built a css customizer where user can modify css from Joomla admin panel (for simplicity - lets just call it php based admin page). The user can then click APPLY CSS button to write the new css file to the server path which will then take over the styling of the website.

Here is my code:

BUTTON - HTML

```
 <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" download="style.css">Get CSS</a>
```

I still need some jQuery because the code below does the trick to generate the css for me and I cannot probably convert that to php:

My JQuery Code:

```
    $("a[download='uikit.css']").on("click", function(e) {
    downloadCSS($(this), $style);
});
```

....
....

```
 a.attr("href", $url.createObjectURL(new Blob([css], {type: "application/force-download"})));
```

Please help me to write PHP function to achieve this.

This is an example of what my button does - http://getuikit.com/docs/customizer.html - The Get CSS button at the bottom dowloads the css file but I would like to overwrite it to a path.

Comment: I think you cannot overwrite the file on server through client side JS due to security. You can load other css on browser but cannot write files on server with JS. You can still achieve your functionality through service side scripting like PHP,JSP, or .NET. Hope that helps, please correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: You could be right and thats a very good point. I use Joomla so I can use php.  Looks like I may have to use php  - Any ideas oh how to convert above download logic to php file overwrite? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have tagged the question to PHP, hope someone will help you from php group :)

Comment: Thanks -PRAH - I did retain some jQuery because some of it is the key to generating the css file.

Comment: Till then you can try this http://www.css-resources.com/write-css-file-with-php.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have the CSS loaded into a form simply POST the form content via Ajax to a php script on your server and use `file_put_contents('/path/to/style.css',$_POST['css'])` to write/overwrite the file.

Alternately, you could just submit the form to the php script and post the data that way.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not in a form. When the button is clicked, the less file gets compiled to css and then the jQuery code force downloads the css file. Your answer would have made perfect sense if a form was involved. Thanks for the answer !!

Comment: Where is the compiled file before it's downloaded?  Can't you just send an ajax request to the server to move it into place?

Comment: It is compiled using a js compiler that is called independently. So when the "Create CSS" button is clicked, the javascript is called and less gets compiled to css. The css then gets downloaded upon the clcik of the button. I will search google to see if I can do what you suggested  "Send ajax request to the server to move in place" but at the moment, I dont know how to do that. Thanks again for your help

Comment: If you are downloading a file then it must exist on your server.  If it exists on your server then you can manipulate it serverside with php.

Comment: ok, That an idea -  I will check how that compiler works and see if it writes to a file or stores in some sort of cache. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Hello Billy - The css is not on the server. It just gets created on the fly when the "get Css" button is clicked by the javascript compiler. Any ideas how I can write it to a server instead of downloading? Thanks

Comment: The css has to exist either client side or server side.  I have given you solutions for both.  Are you even going to upvote my answer?

Comment: I cant upvote your answer. Could you please do me a favor? It will take probably 10 mins for you -  Please download uikit package from here - http://getuikit.com and then put in in localhost. Then navigate to the customizer.html for me? You will see the same thing like this - http://getuikit.com/docs/customizer.html  -  The Get Css button downloads the css -  You will understand what I am asking. Thanks

Comment: Also - Please Note that my html button with the download attribute has a empty HREF.